# Replace variables based upon a value in another file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am new to awk and would like to replace IID in file 1 with regards to the conversion in file 2. Both of these files are txt files.

I have a file **(file 1)** that looks like this (just showing first two columns) and has 2060 rows:

```
FID IID
1   RQ00001-2
2   RQ00002-0
3   RQ00004-9
4   RQ00005-4   
5   RQ00006-5
```

I have another file showing the conversion of the IIDs to another format. This file looks like this:

```
id Id
468768 RQ00001-2
468769 RQ00006-5
468770 RQ00005-4
468771 RQ00002-0
468772 RQ00004-9
```

So I want to replace the **IID** in file 1 with **id** using file 2 as the conversion.  so file 1 should look like this:

```
FID IID
1 468768    
2 468771    
3 468772    
4 468770        
5 468769
```

So I  essentially want to replace IID with id in file 2 using file 2 as the conversion.

I  know I can do this with awk but I am not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It has been done now. My first file has about 2060 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** OP's original question included:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1,$1 in a?a[$1]:$2}' OFS="\t" Input_file2 Input_file1
But I have no idea what this means    ^ and I don't think it's applicable for my problem.
```

---

`$1 in a ? a[$1] : $2` is the [awk ternary operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_ternary_operators.htm).

In this case it reads: if `$1 in a` then output `a[$1]` else output `$2`

For this particular case it's saying that if `$1` (first field of 2nd file) is an index in the `a[]` array then print the contents of the array entry `a[$1]` else print the contents of `$2` (second field of the 2nd file); in other words the ternary operator is determining if you keep the current field #2 value or replace it with a cooresponding value from the array.

Having said that I think there's a problem with the current `awk` code ...

---

Assumptions:

- if `file #1 / field #2` matches `file #2 / field #2` then ...
- replace `file #1 / field #2` with the value from `file #2 / field #1`

One idea for an `awk` modification:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '                          # just my personal preference to list variables first; OP can leave after script and before files

        # process 1st input file

FNR==NR { if ( FNR>1 )                     # skip 1st line "id Id"
             a[$2]=$1                      # 2nd file: 2nd field is index, 1st field is replacement value
          next
        }

        # process 2nd input file

        { print $1,$2 in a ? a[$2] : $2 }  # if 2nd field is an index in array a[] then replace it with said array value else keep current 2nd field 
' Input_file2 Input_file1

 # eliminating comments and pesky white space for a 'compact' one-liner:

 awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR {if(FNR>1)a[$2]=$1;next}{print $1,$2 in a?a[$2]:$2}' Input_file2 Input_file1
```

Both of these generate:

```
FID     IID
1       468768
2       468771
3       468772
4       468770
5       468769
```

**NOTES:**

- OP has mentioned wanting to replace the values in file #1; OP will need to capture the output from this `awk` script into another (temporary) file and then overwrite the original file with this new (temporary) file; it's up to OP to determine if a backup copy of file #1 should be made first
- OP mentions file #1 has more than 2 columns; assuming the number of columns could be 'large' and/or dynamic, OP can make the following change to the code ...

Modifying code to replace `file #1 / field #2` and then print the line:

```
# change from:

{ print $1,$2 in a ? a[$2] : $2 }

# change to:

{ $2 = $2 in a ? a[$2] : $2; print }   # overwrite value in field #2 in current line and then print current line
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. can this work when both my files are different lengths. E.g file 1 is 2060 and file 2 is 4224. File 2 has extra IDs  essentially.

Comment: number of rows should not be a problem; since this `awk` code does not overwrite the original file I'd suggest you run the code against your files and verify the resulting output (*When in doubt, try it out!*)